# Grant permissions to folder in Sharepoint library using Powershell?

Tags: security, powershell, sharepoint, csv, sharepoint-2010

I have a Sharepoint Library, which I have a Powershell script dropping files into for processing. The Powershell script reaches out to Active Directory, and returns Group Membership information. The script then creates a folder for the group owner (if it doesn't exist) in my Library, using the group owners' name, and drops a .CSV of all the users contained in the specific group into that folder.

The need here, is to grant 'Read' permissions only to the owner of the group, which will be the name of the folder we are working in. Ideally the folder would be hidden, however I understand that there are limitations when working with Sharepoint.

For example:

> John Doe, User: jdoe would be able to access Z:/jdoe/IT.csv but not
>   Z:/someuser/HR.csv

I have my Sharepoint Library mapped to Z:/ currently, to make my life easier for Powershell.

I executed `get-command  Module Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell | ft name` and ran through the list of Sharepoint Commands.

I then stumbled across the `Grant-SPObjectSecurity Cmdlet`, which I assume is what I would want to use on the Powershell side to, when the folder is being created, apply Sharepoint permissions only to the user for which the folder is being created for.

The process from start to finish is: Powershell Script 'Get_Group_Members' executes, reading a text file containing an Active Directory Group name, per line. For each group found, the script identifies the owner of the group, creates a folder named with the owners AD name, and puts a .CSV file in the folder listing all members of the group. Then, I (for now anyway) manually initiate the next Script 'Import_CSV' which pulls all the information into a Sharepoint list for an unrelated process.

Hope that helps understand what's happening. Am I right in assuming I should handle this on the Powershell side, as opposed to the Sharepoint side? If so, am I headin' in the right direction with `Grant -SPObjectSecurity`?

Thanks!

**Update:**

Following the link I provided in a comment below, here is what I came up with:

```
function GrantUserpermission($strOwnerName)
    {
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection]$spusers=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection]$web.SiteUsers
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser]$spuser=$spusers[$strOwnerName]

        "Strowner name: " + $strOwnerName

        # Get the SPWeb object and save it to a variable
        $web = Get-SPWeb -identity $WebURL
        if ($strOwnerName -ne $null)

        {
            $sproleass=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPPrincipal]$spuser)
            $folder.BreakRoleInheritance("true")
            $sproleass.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"])
            $folder.RoleAssignments.Add($sproleass);
            Write-Host "Permission provided for user ", $strOwnerName
        }

        else

        {

        Write-Host "User ""$userName"" was not found in this web!"

        }

   }
```

And here, are the error(s) associated with my code:

[image]

Full code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/iBpj6V1U

**Update #2**

```
#apply permissions to folder
    "Strowner name: " + $strOwnerName
    function GrantUserpermission($strOwnerName)
    {

    $web = Get-SPWeb -identity $WebURL
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser]$spuser=$web.EnsureUser($strOwnerName)
    "Strowner name in Function: " + $strOwnerName
```

[image]

Updated code #2: http://pastebin.com/DzP1hVce

Comment: [This link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/31fcaf17-6f7d-43ae-b3f2-bc5694493d1b/set-permission-to-document-library-folder-using-powershell?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) highlights a quick way to do something similar to what I am asking, but uses the command `RoleDefinitionBindings.Add` which I am not sure applies properly to my scenario. Any insight?

Comment: The link which provided proposes correct solution to how grant permissions on a folder. Have you tried that? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets I have updated my question with the code I have modified from the link provided, and the accompanying errors that came along with it.

Comment: 1) You get this error because your $web variable is declared after you trying to access users collection. Put "$web = Get-SPWeb -identity $WebURL" at the beginning of the function. 
2) You need to provide boolean value to BreakRoleInheritance method not string. Replace "$folder.BreakRoleInheritance("true")" with $folder.BreakRoleInheritance($true)
3) I would suggest to use EnsureUser method to get user by name instead of lookup SiteUsers collection directly.[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser]$spuser=$web.EnsureUser($strOwnerName)

Comment: I am giving this a shot today, along with a few other methods.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets I have updated (#2) my question. Now, I've made progress, however I am confused as to why my $strOwner string contains the correct information before my function is executed, however during the execution it loses the string $strOwner and I am not sure why? I have also tried moving the function to the beginning of the file with no success. Thanks!!

Comment: You have overlapping in your GrantUserpermission function and in script scope - $strOwnerName. Remove parameter for GrantUserpermission  function. GrantUserpermission ()

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets that helped. It appears to be working in console, however something isn't right on the Sharepoint end as the permissions didn't get applied to anything for anyone. I think that it's because the string $strOwnerName isn't a FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) at this point, so I'm going to re-work the code a bit and let you know if I am successful in a bit! Thanks for the help thus far.

Comment: I tried making it a FQDN, per this article msdn.microsoft.com/library/… (I know it's not specifically for Powershell but at least I was trying SOMETHING haha) and it couldn't find the user, so that wasn't the issue. 
I've modified the 'GrantUserPermission' function, and in console it's breaking on lines 18 & 19 & 20:  `$folder.BreakRoleInheritance($true)$sproleass.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($web.RoleDefinitions["ApproveItems"]) $folder.RoleAssignments.Add($sproleass);` ...and this is what the error message is: http://i.imgur.com/oaKYdxA.png Thanks @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets

Comment: I do not see in your code that you initialize $folder variable. That what errors says - $folder variable is not initialized.

Comment: I declared on line: 96 in the following Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/tB8VhE99

It's still barking about that "Method invocation failed because [System.String] doesn't contain a method named 'BreakRo
leInheritance'." 

Seen here: http://i.imgur.com/wDpGtsN.png

Am I missing something system specific here such as a runtime or add in? @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets

Comment: $folder variable should contain SharePoint SPFolder object not string.

Comment: Do `$Target = $Web.Folders | ?{$_.Name -eq $strOwnerName}` and then change your `$Folder.BreakRole` and `$Folder.RoleAssign` lines to `$Target.BreakRole` and `$Target.RoleAssign` to fix the object type reference errors.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician thanks to some useful advise from a member of the Sharepoint Stack Exchange community, I reworked the process, skipping file manipulation completely, and tapping right into Sharepoint. Think smarter, not harder right? 

http://pastebin.com/xRyvXLCB

That's the code I ended up using, if anyone else would happen to be reading through the trail of threads I leave in the wake of this project. Thank you for helping me stumble along the way, you have proven to be most helpful to the Stack Overflow community!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up realizing, that if I am using Powershell to get information to a .CSV, and then ultimately to Sharepoint, that it doesn't make sense to actually waste time with files, and tap directly into Sharepoint via Powershell.

Here's the code I had used to accomplish this: http://pastebin.com/xRyvXLCB

Special thanks to @TheMadTechnician

Comment: Nice clean script, glad to see everything worked out so well, and thank you for posting your end solution for future users.